# Wpf Set Global Style for Mahapps.Metro NumericUpDown Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am learning Mahapps.Metro in WPF. I want to set global style for NumericUpDown Control of Mahapps.Metro.

I have added this in App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:NumericUpDown}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" /></Style>
```

But It's not working.

If i set in individual form then it's working. Like:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:NumericUpDown">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" /> </Style>
```